# How would I go about finding multiple integers at the same time, then executing a print command based off those integers

Tags: python, integer

I am trying to create a program that will find every number with a square root, cube root, quarter root, and quintuple root under 2^60.  Every time I run the command I get only every square number, which is what I programmed variable Num1 to be.

code:

```
Num = 1
Num1 = 1

while Num1 < 1152921504606846976:

    Num += 2
    Num1 += Num

    Num2 = Num1 ** 0.5
    Num3 = Num1 ** 0.33333333333333333333
    Num4 = Num1 ** 0.25
    Num5 = Num1 ** 0.2

    if Num1 > Num:
        float(Num2).is_integer()and float(Num3).is_integer()and float(Num4).is_integer() and float(Num5).is_integer()
        print Num1
    else:
        null
```

Sorry for bad code I am REALLY new to this. 
Num2 - Num5 are the answers of the number Num1 being rooted, and if they are all integers my goal is to have a print command give the original number, Num1

Comment: This program is bound to fail. On top of being very inefficient, try `1000**0.33333333333333333333`, you won't get `10`. You shouldn't use floats for this type of tests...

Comment: Do you mean every *integer* number with square roots....?

Comment: You're not asking the program to print Num1

Answer (score 1):

As Julien pointed out using floats in this probem is problematic due to the precision issues. Furthermore, you are doing an iteration until 2 ^ 60, which may be pretty slow.

**Simple but slow approach**

A simple approach would be generate all the integers that have square roots, then all the integers that have cubic roots, and so on. After that, do an intersection of all the numbers we generated so far.

That process can be done easily, we need to iterate from **1** until **n^(1/k)** to generate numbers that have kth-roots, if **i^k** is less or equal than our max number, then we have found an kth-root. The code:

```
def kth_roots(n, k):
  i = 1
  ans = []
  while i ** k <= n:
    ans.append(i ** k)
    i += 1

  return ans

n = 2 ** 60
two = kth_roots(n, 2)
three = kth_roots(n, 3)
four = kth_roots(n, 4)
five = kth_roots(n, 5)

answer = set(two) & set(three) & set(four) & set(five)
print(answer)
```

**An approach based on divisibility**

I will propose an answer asuming that you will have your maximum number expressed as a power in the form **x ^ y**.

Note that, a number will have an integer square root if it can be expressed as **b ^ e**, such that **e** is divisible by two, it will have a integer cube root if **e** is divisible by three, and so on. So a better approach, is to check which exponents will satisfy your conditions (divisibility by 2, 3, 4, and 5). Finally we must determine the value of **b**, we can brute force, and stop whenever it is greater than **x ^ y**.

In this way we do not have to play with float numbers that may be a headache here. Some code:

```
max_exp = 60
max_base = 2
maxm = max_base ** max_exp

ans = 0
e = 1
print(1) # Trivial case
while True:
  if e % 2 == 0 and e % 3 == 0 and e % 4 == 0 and e % 5 == 0:
    b = 2
    flag = False
    while b ** e <= maxm:
      flag = True
      print(b ** e)
      b += 1

    if flag is False:
      break

  e += 1
```

EDIT: As Hugh Bothwel mentioned, the divisibility check on the powers can be reduced to compute the LCM of [2,3,4,5], that would be 60, so any number **a^60** have the mentioned integer roots. All that remains is to brute force the values of **a**. The code:

```
from fractions import gcd

def _lcm(x, y):
  return (x * y) // gcd(x, y)


maxm = 2 ** 60
lcm = reduce(_lcm, [2, 3, 4, 5], 1)

a = 1
while a ** lcm <= maxm:
  print(a ** lcm)
  a += 1
```

Comment: ... and LCM(2,3,4,5) is 60 (2^2 * 3 * 5), so you are looking for every number <= 2^60 which can be written as n^60 -->  n E {1,2}